# SQL Query- for each class with at least three ships, give the number of ships of that class that were sunk

Tags: sql

Need help with this problem please:

Given the schema 
 Classes (class, type, country, numGuns, bore, displacement) 
 Ships (name, class, launched) 
 Battles (name, date) 
 Outcomes (shipname, battle, result)

(a) Write a query in SQL to find “for each class with at least three ships, the number of ships of that class that were sunk in battle”.

Comment: Do your own homework.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT random() AS ships_sunk_in_battle;

Comment: can you explain to me please. The function of random()

Comment: Pretty sure that was meant as a sarcastic joke. And I almost liked it enough to upvote it.